# how to assign values to textbox inside html cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: this is my html table]

i want to assign value to this textboxes using javascript

i'll try it usig this

```
(table.rows.item(i).cells[5]).find('input').val("45");
```

but it wouldn't happen
[image]
i'm append my table like this

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#invoiceDetailTbl > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+1)').remove();
    var date;
    var invDate;
    var invNo;
    var netAmt;
    var paidAmt;
    var balance;
    var totalAmt = 0;
    var totalBalance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        date = data[i].inv_Date;
        invDate = date.substring(0, 10);
        invNo = data[i].inv_No;
        netAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Net_Amt).toFixed(2);
        paidAmt = parseFloat(data[i].Paid_Amt).toFixed(2);
        balance = (parseFloat(netAmt) - parseFloat(paidAmt)).toFixed(2); //id = "damt['+i+']"
        $("#invoiceDetailTbl tbody").append("<tr id=" + i + ">" + "<td>" + invDate + "</td>" + "<td>" + invNo + "</td>" + "<td>" + netAmt + "</td>" + "<td>" + paidAmt + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<input type="text" class="discountAmt form-control input-sm" style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Discount Amt" id="damt">' + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<input type="text" class="payingAmt form-control input-sm" style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Paying Amt" id="pamt">' + "</td>" + "<td>" + balance + "</td>" + "<td>" + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>' + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        totalAmt = totalAmt + parseFloat(netAmt);
        totalBalance = totalBalance + parseFloat(balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(table.rows.item(i).cells[5]).find('input').val("45");`

Comment: By looking at your [previously asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210560/read-value-from-textbox-inside-html-table-cell), I think you should do it yourself, don't you think so? –  Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: i'd try it using (table.rows.item(i).cells[5]).find('input').val("45"); but it didn't happen.. :)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/wz89n4pg/?

Comment: please share the HTML of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table.rows.item(i).cells[5])` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. So you cannot invoke find on it.

try

`$(table.rows.item(i).cells[5])).find('input').val("45");`

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#invoiceDetailTbl tbody").rows.item(i).cells[5]).find('input').val("45")`. are u trying it inside the ajax call??